# Rails slim syntax errors - config wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I just merged the redesign branch in our rails app, and now we use slim. Everyone seems to have it working fine, but if I try browsing the new website (without any code modification), I get syntax errors like:

```
unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
```

Here is a snippet of the slim file, above error is on the last line, but I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with the file as others devs don't have the problem, neither does the production site.

```
#featured-destinations-carousel.carousel.slide data-ride="carousel" data-interval="15000"
  .pagination.hidden-sm.hidden-xs
    = link_to "#featured-destinations-carousel", 'data-slide': 'prev' do
```

I was told to upgrade to Ruby 2.2+, I did (with rbenv), but that didn't fix it. Ideas?

Comment: Should `data-slide: 'prev'` or `:data-slide => 'prev'`

Comment: @ShabbirAhmed neither of those will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your upgrade hasn't worked properly, the Rails app is still using and older version of Ruby. Make sure your rbenv is set up properly (do `ruby -v` and `which ruby` to help debug before running `rails s`) and that your `.ruby-version` file has the correct version in it.

Comment: `ruby -v`, `which ruby` and `.ruby-version` all correctly point to 2.2.4. But after reboot I stumbled upon a version problem at last... `rails s` throws a `Gem::LoadError` in `/usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb`, so still 2.0.0. No idea how I messed this up and how I can recover.

Comment: What about `bundle exec rails s`? That looks like its using your system gems rather than ones included with rbenv. `which ruby` should point to `~/.rbenv/shims/ruby`. You should double check that your `.bash_profile` correctly initializes rbenv (check out the readme).

Comment: indeed, bin/rails and bundle exec rails work fine. I went from rbenv to rvm, and even though ruby is the rvm one, rails is taken from the system. I'll check the rvm doc about that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're super close. Just need to change it to

```
= link_to "#featured-destinations-carousel", 'data-slide' => 'prev' do
```

instead.

Comment: That just changes it to ruby < 2.2 syntax rather than fix the underlying problem of the wrong version being used.